# How to configure kdiff3 instead of emerge as a git mergetool?

Tags: macos, git, merge, config, kdiff3

I have Git on mac OSX Snow Leopard and I tried to edit my merge and diff tool to use kdiff3 instead of emerge.

But when I try to use it does not launch the GUI of kdiff and keeps me with a cmd based interface.

My setting in gitconfig are:

```
[merge]
     tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    cmd = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
    args = $base $local $other -o $output
    trustExitCode = false
[diff]
tool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
cmd = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
args = $base $local $other -o $output
trustExitCode = false
```

There is obviously something missing but what did I do wrong ?

Comment: it would help to post the command you use for diff

Comment: sure I did git difftool -t kdiff3 and git mergetool -t kdiff3

Comment: Just installed kdiff3 with brew and mine works without defining `[mergetool]` or `[difftool]`. Just `tool = kdiff3`.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Recent Git versions have built-in support for `kdiff3`, so there's no need to configure it manually using the generic *cmd* and *args* settings. Instead do:

```
$ git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
```

And if `kdiff3` is not in your *PATH* environment also do:

```
$ git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.path /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

This makes `git mergetool` launch `kdiff3`. Note that [there is no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032265/how-do-i-make-git-automatically-open-the-mergetool-if-there-is-a-merge-conflict) to configure Git to *automatically* launch your merge tool after a manual merge that has conflicts.

In case you really want to see how Git is calling `kdiff3` internally, take a look at [the built-in mergetool configuration for kdiff3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/kdiff3).

**Edit**: For [Beyond Compare 4](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=v4whatsnew), which now also supports Mac OS X, simply exchange `kdiff3` with `bc3` (yes, "3") and adjust the path in the above lines. Starting with Git 2.2.0 you'll be able to use `bc` as an alias for `bc3` so that you do not have to care about the version number.

Comment: I still had to install kdiff3.  If you have homebrew, it's as easy as `brew install kdiff3`.  That should be enough to put kdiff3 in the path.

Comment: git config --global diff.tool kdiff3

Comment: @mikelong If `diff.tool` is not configured it falls back to `merge.tool`, so just configuring the latter is enough.

Comment: @sschuberth I'm having the same problem with Meld for mac, does your solution also work for that? Seems like editting gitignore based on Meld for Mac instructions doesn't do the trick

Comment: @SabaAhang My instructions work for any diff / merge tool that is directly supported by Git, and that includes `meld`. The list of supported tools can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/mergetools), or by running `git mergetool --tool-help`.

Comment: If you are trying to install from homebrew, kdiff3 has been moved to cask.  To install it now you'll need to `brew tap caskroom/cask` and then `brew cask install kdiff3`

Comment: Did everything as written still opens terminal as `mergetool`.

Answer (score 1):

> Recent Git versions have built-in support for kdiff3

Yes, but only Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) will allow those built-in tools to trust their exit code.

See [commit 2967284](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2967284456e9053ee8dd26148c22432a4776a3dc), [commit 7c10605](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c10605d2ccf499af6136e993cf248892be39168) (29 Nov 2016) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c4a44e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4a44e23e03c4a1558a21c15bb880c9411a37fd5), 16 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `mergetool`: honor `mergetool.$tool.trustExitCode` for built-in tools
>
> Built-in merge tools contain a hard-coded assumption about whether or not a tool's exit code can be trusted to determine the success or failure of a merge.
>   Tools whose exit codes are not trusted contain calls to `check_unchanged()` in their `merge_cmd()` functions.
>
> A problem with this is that the trustExitCode configuration is not honored for built-in tools.
>
> Teach built-in tools to honor the `trustExitCode` configuration.

(See [`kdiff3`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c10605d2ccf499af6136e993cf248892be39168#diff-0bbf812394d566ca5937838e13d50091))

> Extend `run_merge_cmd()` so that it is responsible for calling `check_unchanged()` when a tool's exit code cannot be trusted.
>   Remove `check_unchanged()` calls from scriptlets since they are no longer responsible for calling it.